# Combine of information based on two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my sample data

```
> data.frame
              a     b     c     d 
W_1_N        NA    NA    NA    NA  
W_1_E         2     2     2     4   
W_1_C         4     2     2     4  
W_1_D        NA    NA    NA    NA
```

First I had to combine elements from matrix to get pairs of column names of them, where one of element is 4 and another is 2 in the same row.

In a result it looks like this

```
W_1_E.1  d  a
W_1_E.2  d  b
W_1_E.3  d  c
W_1_C.1  a  b
W_1_C.2  a  c
W_1_C.3  d  b
W_1_C.4  d  c
```

I wanted only pairs where one element is 4 and other is 2 in the same row. W_1_N and W_1_D have only  NA so was ommited. W_1_E appears in 3 rows because there are 3 pairs of (4,2) in row in sample data.W_1_C has 4 pairs.

This is code:

```
  lst=data.frame(df) %>%
    rownames_to_column("rn") %>%
    drop_na() %>%
    gather(key, value, -rn) %>%
    group_by(rn, value) %>%
    summarise(l = list(unique(key))) %>%
    split(.$rn)

pair=do.call("rbind", lapply(lst, function(x) expand.grid(x$l[[1]], 
x$l[[2]])))
```

It works perfectly, but now I have second data.frame:

```
              a     b     c     d 
W_1_N         0     1     1     1  
W_1_E         1     1     0     0   
W_1_C         1     1     1     0  
W_1_D         1     0     1     1
```

Here is my problem, I want to get only this pairs where value of both elements of pair is `1` in second data.frame. For example first pair of my result `W_1_E.1  d  a` should be eliminated because `d` has value `0` in `W_1_E` row in second data.frame.

The output should be:

```
W_1_C.1  a  b
W_1_C.2  a  c
```

`d` has value `0` in `W_1_E` row, so all rows with `W_1_E` in my result data.frame were eliminated (all pars were with `d`). The last two rows were eliminated because `d` is also `0` in `W_1_C` row in second dataframe.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your expected output?  Is it the one after the first exxample

Comment: My expected output is the one after first example but only with this pairs where value of both elements of pair is 1.

Comment: @akrun do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
x <- "N             a     b     c     d 
W_1_N        NA    NA    NA    NA  
W_1_E         2     2     2     4   
W_1_C         4     2     2     4  
W_1_D        NA    NA    NA    NA "
x1 <- read.table(text = x, header = TRUE)

x <- "N             a     b     c     d 
W_1_N         0     1     1     1  
W_1_E         1     1     0     0   
W_1_C         1     1     1     0  
W_1_D         1     0     1     1  "
x2 <- read.table(text = x, header = TRUE)

df <- merge(x1, x2, by="N")
df$a <- ifelse(df$a.y == 0,NA,df$a.x)
df$b <- ifelse(df$b.y == 0,NA,df$b.x)
df$c <- ifelse(df$c.y == 0,NA,df$c.x)
df$d <- ifelse(df$d.y == 0,NA,df$d.x)
df <- df[ , c(1,10:13)]


library(tidyr)
df_all <- df %>%
  gather(key = key1, value, 2:5)

df2 <- df_all[!is.na(df_all$value) & df_all$value == 2,]
df4 <- df_all[!is.na(df_all$value) & df_all$value == 4,]
merge(df2[,1:2], df4[1:2], by = "N", all.x = FALSE, all.y = FALSE)
```

Comment: I should change my data.frame to text first? ANd where I define my second data.frame with `0` and `1`?

Comment: No. If you do `str(df)` you will see all my values are integer.

Comment: It gives me pairs of elements of first dataframe. My problem is to eliminate this pairs in which one of element has value 0.

Comment: Can you show the output that you expect t get once you have eliminated pairs in which one element is zero?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I've just updated it, have a look now. Not my prettiest code but I think it does the job.